# Should the Default Gateway be Firewall or DHCP/DNS server on Windows Domain Client PC

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

This is a bit of a theorteical question but it determines how I set up.

On a Client computer within a Windows network should the "Default Gateway" be set to the Firewall or the DHCP server (which would then direct it to the Firewall)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DHCP server isn't a router and can't "direct" traffic to your router. You assign the ip address of your router to the DHCP clients via DHCP but the DHCP server itself has no hand in routing traffic.